# Prove the real derivative matrix is invertible if and only if $f′(z)=0$

Tags: complex-analysis

let $f$ be analytic in a neighborhood of $z$. Show that the real derivative
of $f$, $Df(x,y) : R^2 → R^2$ is invertible at $z = x + iy$ if and only if $f'(z)=0$.

My thought is:
$Df(x,y) :(x,y)\to(f_x,f_y)$ is not invertible $\Longleftrightarrow$Jocobi determinant of $Df(x,y): \begin{bmatrix}f_{xx}&f_{xy}\\f_{yx}&f_{yy}\end{bmatrix}= 0\Longleftrightarrow f_{xx}f_{yy}-f_{xy}f_{yx} =0 \Longleftrightarrow f_{xx}= if_{yx} ~\&~f_{xy}= if_{yy}\Longleftrightarrow f_x= if_y\Longleftrightarrow\frac{1}{2}(f_x-if_y)=0\Longleftrightarrow f'(z)=0$

But it seems wrong in the second$\Longleftrightarrow$. So how to supplement more details?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: The real derivative of $f=u+iv$ is the matrix
$$
\begin{bmatrix} u_x & u_y \\ v_x & v_y \end{bmatrix}
$$
Compute the deterimant.  Now apply the Cauchy Riemann equations and the fact that $f' = u_x + iv_x$.  Then $f'(z) \not= 0$ means that at $z$ either $u_x$ or $v_x$ is not zero.